# Вылетает приложение при переходе на следующий экран

Tags: android, android-studio, исключения, libgdx

Есть игра, написанная в Android Studio, которая всякий раз вылетает, когда, например, из меню нужно нажать на кнопку Start и как бы перейти на следующий экран.

Ошибки в ивентлоге во время нажатия и вылета нет никакой, а вот когда я выключаю эмулятор, то в ивентлоге написано **Emulator: qemu-system-i386.exe: Unable to open C:\Users\loh.android\avd\Nexus_6P_API_24.avd\data\misc\pstore\pstore.bin: Permission denied**  (да, юзер именуется как ЛОХ)

Хотя доступ у меня везде свободный...
Но не в этом, наверное, суть, хотя разобраться хотелось бы

В logcat во время вылета следующее:

```
**EXCEPTION: GLThread 449
Process: com.mygdx.game, PID: 16508
java.lang.IllegalStateException: SpriteBatch.end must be called before begin.
at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.SpriteBatch.begin(SpriteBatch.java:169)
at com.mygdx.game.states.PlayState.render(PlayState.java:34)
at com.mygdx.game.states.GameStateManager.render(GameStateManager.java:38)
at com.mygdx.game.FlappyDemo.render(FlappyDemo.java:41)
at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidGraphics.onDrawFrame(AndroidGraphics.java:495)
at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.guardedRun(GLSurfaceView.java:1553)
at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.run(GLSurfaceView.java:1253)
02-25 19:48:22.853 16508-16508/com.mygdx.game E/AndroidGraphics: waiting for
pause synchronization took too long; assuming deadlock and killing
02-25 19:48:22.853 16508-16508/com.mygdx.game I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 16508 SIG: 9**
```

Comment: `SpriteBatch.end must be called before begin.`

Comment: как конец может быть вызван до начала?